# Usar SUBSTRING en MySQL en un sentencia UPDATE

Tags: mysql

```
UPDATE Tabla SET Comentario=SUBSTRING('Es una cadena larga pero solo quiero los cinco primeros caracteres', 5)
```

Tengo esta consulta en la cual quiero que me actualice *Comentario* con solo los 5 primeros caracteres de la cadena que le paso, pero me lo actualiza en blanco.

¿Cómo puedo actualizar un campo con un *substring* de una cadena dada?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intenta esto.

```
UPDATE Tabla SET Comentario=SUBSTRING('Es una cadena larga pero solo quiero los cinco primeros caracteres', 1, 5)
```

En mi consideración, lo que faltaría es que asignes la posición de la palabra que quieres traer de la frase. La primera sería 1.

Intenta por favor

Comment: OK, me ha funcionado perfecto, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Lo correcto es usar `left(cadena, cantidad de caracteres)` o `right(cadena, cantidad de caracteres)` dependiendo si es por el principio o el final del texto, cuando es dentro sí se usa substring, además agrega la cláusula where para especificar los renglones que serán afectados.

```
UPDATE Tabla SET Comentario=left('Es una cadena larga pero solo quiero los cinco primeros caracteres', 5);
```